# Retrieve innerHTML of a diffrent page using $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

So I tried getting the innerHtml of an Element of a diffrent page (SOP friendly).

For example:

```
$.get("/archiveIDs.htm", function(data){
      alert($(data).find('a#1163').html());
});
```

I tried getting the innerHtml of an `<a>`-Tag with ID 1163. Thats doenst work... 
I dont know what to do now.
If u have any ideas please reply to this post.

Thanks in advance, Freddy!

Comment: see data on console using `console.log(data)` first.

Comment: I think data is just text, not a DOM element, that's why find method doesn't work.

Comment: I tried `alert($(data).find('a#1163').text());`aswell and it didnt work either :(

Comment: @Hekmat console showed no errors, just Object {readyState: 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
$.get("/archiveIDs.htm", function(data){
  var html=$('<div />').html(data).find('a#1163').html();
  alert(html); });
```

Comment: Great job man, its working! Thank you very much, but why `('<div />').html`? :d

Comment: Just storing the retrieved HTML into memory for finding the element (a#1163)

Comment: It will create a DOM element in the memory

Comment: oh yesss very clever ;) greets freddy

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
$.get("/archiveIDs.htm", function(data){
     console.log($('#1163', data).html());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this contribution, but this doesnt work. It says undefined...